# Getting Selected Rows Count in QTableWidget - PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, selection, qtablewidget

In the `python` `plugin`, I'm developing, I need to retrieve the number of selected rows in a `QTableWidget`. I can loop through each row of the `QTableWidget` and check them whether it is selected or not. Instead, Is there a straightforward way to get the selected rows count of a `QTableWidget` in `PyQt`?

**Something like:**

> QTableWidget.selectedRowsCount()

Comment: What is your selection behavior? Is it set to SelectItems or SelectRows?

Comment: @BrendanAbel It is selectedRows (rows selection  when clicking row header)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the number of rows that are *fully selected* (i.e. as when clicking on a row header):

```
len(tableWidget.selectionModel().selectedRows())
```

But if you want rows which just have *at least one cell selected*:

```
len(set(index.row() for index in tableWidget.selectedIndexes()))
```

Comment: That worked !! `len(tableWidget.selectionModel().selectedRows())` is the one which I need **(selecting the entire row)**.

Answer (score 1):

`len(tablewidget.selectedIndexes())` should probably do what you want.